# How to use an optional key to access a dictionary value?

Tags: swift, swift-dictionary

I have an optional value that I would like to use to index a Dictionary.

How can I do that without having to 'dirty' my code with `if let`/`else`?

e.g.

```
if
    let key = type(of: self).notificationValueKeys[notification.name],
    let value = notification.userInfo?[key] {

    self.value = value

} else {

   self.value = nil
}
```

Comment: Use guard statement

Comment: whoops, the return statement snuck in there and shouldn't have been in the else block

Comment: Why not (without if - else)  `let key = type(of: self).notificationValueKeys[notification.name]` `self.value = key != nil ? notification.userInfo?[key!] : nil` ?

Answer (score 5):

One elegant way to do this is with an extension to `Dictionary` to allow the subscript (`[]`) operator on `Dictionary` work with optional keys:

```
/**
 convenience subscript operator for optional keys

 - parameter key
 - returns: value or nil
 */
subscript(key: Key?) -> Value? {

    guard let key = key else { return nil }
    return self[key]
}
```

This allows the above code to become:

```
let key = type(of: self).notificationValueKeys[notification.name]
let value = notification.userInfo?[key]

self.value = value
```

Where `let value` is now optional.